# Linear Algebra Matrices and Det

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Explain in terms of volumes why $\det 3A=3^n \det A$ for an n by n matrix $A$.

What am I suppose to do here?

Comment: The idea is that the determinant gives you the volume of the solid "parallelepiped" given by the three row vectors in the matrix --meaning $A$; not the movie! . So if you multiply your matrix by $3$, you're multiplying each vector component, i.e., each "side"-length by 3.